# Radix in hexadecimal

Tags: hex, radix-sort, radix

Pierre Terdiman in his article "Radix Sort Revisited" tells us:

> For example you’ll need 4 passes to sort standard 32 bits integers,
>   since in hexadecimal the radix is a byte.

But 0xAB has two radices, namely A and B, 4-bit wide either.

So, what is the radix in hexadecimal? Because i can't understand the article.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understand, the `0xAB` was just an example to what radix is. When approaching Radix sort, it's easier to use bytes (no need for shifting - only casting, in `C/C++`, anyway).

The last part of the sentence is the important thing here:

> since in hexadecimal the radix is a byte

After saying that, it doesn't matter what was said earlier...

Just to strengthen the argument, examine his example - the `SortedBuffer` initialization uses byte as radix (`256*sizeof(int)`), not nibble:

```
memset(SortedBuffer, -1, 256*sizeof(int));   // Fill with –1
```

(again, from I understand in this article...)